# Switching tabs with the mouse wheel

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, google-chrome-extensions

Normally I use Opera, but a certain CMS I am managing fails to support it and works best in Chrome due to gratuitous JavaScript. I am looking for some way to be able to switch tabs in Chrome by holding RMB and scrolling, preferably in order of last tab access time.

Comment: If you hover the mouse pointer over the browser tabs the mousewheel does change which tab is active.

Comment: @AlEverett that sounds useful, but doesn't seem to work for me. Do I need to enable it somehow?

Comment: Not as far as I know. I didn't realize it did that until I tried it yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

I personnally use SmoothGestures. It's been withdrawn from the chrome webstore, but you can still get it from it [Project page](http://code.google.com/p/smoothgestures-chromium/).

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather avoid installing spyware.

Comment: As far as I understood the controversy, the developer made a stupid move to try to achieve some goal unrelated to spywaring, and removed the guilty line as soon as the first critics started. But of course it's ultimately your choice :)